# SelectionGroup not adding extra attributes

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have the PHP code:

```
SelectionGroup::create(
//...
SelectionGroup_Item::create(/*...*/),
SelectionGroup_Item::create(/*...*/),
//...
)
->addExtraClass("some-extra-class")
->setAttribute('ng-change','log(myModel)')
->setAttribute('ng-model','myModel')
```

and the rendered html looks like:

```
...
<ul class="SelectionGroup field CompositeField selectiongroup some-extra-class nolabel">
    ...
</ul>
...
```

My extra class is being added, why aren't my extra attributes being added?

---

This `SelectionGroup` is part of a `FieldList`, other `Field`s allow attributes to be set, and `Field`s within the `SelectionGroup_Item` can have their attributes set eg:

```
FieldList::create([
  HiddenField::create(...)->setAttribute("does","this work"),
  SelectionGroup::create(
    //...
    SelectionGroup_Item::create('name',
      FieldGroup::create(null,[
        HiddenField::create(...)->setAttribute("maybe","it does")
      ])
    ),
    SelectionGroup_Item::create(...),
    //...
  )
  ->addExtraClass("some-extra-class")
  ->setAttribute('ng-change','log(myModel)')
  ->setAttribute('ng-model','myModel')
])
```

Renders the following HTML:

```
...
<input type="hidden" ... does="this work" />
<ul class="SelectionGroup field CompositeField selectiongroup some-extra-class nolabel">
  ...
  <input type="hidden" ... maybe="it does" />
  ...
</ul>
...
```

Comment: Which version of SS are you on?

Comment: @RobbieAverill 3.4 (stable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.4 the `$AttributesHTML` variable is not called in the default template that `SelectionGroup_Item` uses.

`SelectionGroup_Item` uses the `CompositeField` template (as it [extends `CompositeField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SelectionGroup_Item.html) and it does not have it's own template set in framework).

The current `CompositeField` template in framework does not include `$AttributesHTML` in the opening tag:

```
<$Tag class="CompositeField $extraClass <% if ColumnCount %>multicolumn<% end_if %>">
    <% if $Tag == 'fieldset' && $Legend %>
        <legend>$Legend</legend>
    <% end_if %>

    <% loop $FieldList %>
        <% if $ColumnCount %>
            <div class="column-{$ColumnCount} $FirstLast">
                $Field
            </div>
        <% else %>
            $Field
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
</$Tag>
```

We can create our own `SelectionGroup_Item` template or `CompositeField` to add the `$AttributesHTML` variable in.

To do this we create a `SelectionGroup_Item.ss` file in our `mysite/templates/includes` directory.

**mysite/templates/includes/SelectionGroup_Item.ss**

```
<$Tag $AttributesHTML class="CompositeField $extraClass <% if ColumnCount %>multicolumn<% end_if %>">
    <% if $Tag == 'fieldset' && $Legend %>
        <legend>$Legend</legend>
    <% end_if %>

    <% loop $FieldList %>
        <% if $ColumnCount %>
            <div class="column-{$ColumnCount} $FirstLast">
                $Field
            </div>
        <% else %>
            $Field
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
</$Tag>
```

After creating this template we need to call `?flush=all` in the page URL for the system to clear it's cache and find this new template.

Comment: well that's a shame, I thought this would've been implemented by default... I guess it's hard to implement everything everywhere